# MVC same object is passed to @Html.Partial()...?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am stuck in a thing.

```
@foreach (BLL.Report.ReportSection section in @Model) {
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Report/_ReportSection", section)
}
```

`@Model` is containing two objects with ids 1,2

On load of partial view

```
["~/Views/Report/_ReportSection" ]
```

It is calling ajax call to get data from DB.

I debugged this section object. These are fine and separate objects.
but on load it is getting second object both times.

When ajax call is made to controller it is is always passing data of second object (id = 2).

and loading same result to view.

Please advise what I am missing.?

UPDATE
Sorry for late..

This is complete code in _ReportSection partial view.
on ready function ajax call is made and with return data it is creating table

```
<div id="Section-@Model.ReportId-@Model.SectionId">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {// alert("text-"+@Model.SectionId);
        getSectionData();
    });

    function getSectionData(){
        alert(@Model.ReportId+" -- "+@Model.SectionId);
        CallAjax("GET",
            "json",
            "/ReportTemplate/GetSectionData",
            { ReportId: @Model.ReportId, SectionId: @Model.SectionId },
            getSectionDataSuccess,
            getSectionDataFail)

    }

    function getSectionDataSuccess(data)
    {
        var table = $('<table></table>');
        var rowHeader = $('<th></th>');
        $.each(data, function(index,column) {
            var cell = $('<td></td>').text(column.ColHeader);
            rowHeader.append(cell);
        });
        table.append(rowHeader);

        $.each(data[0].columnDataList, function(index,colObj)
        {
            var row = $('<tr id="@Model.SectionId-'+colObj.RowId+'"></tr>');
            table.append(row);
        });


        $.each(data, function(index,colObj)
        {
            $.each(colObj.columnDataList, function(index,colData)
            {
                var td = $('<td id="@Model.SectionId-'+colData.RowId+'-'+colData.ColName.trim()+'">'+colData.Data.trim()+'</td>');

                var row = $(table).find('#@Model.SectionId-'+colData.RowId);

                $(table).find('#@Model.SectionId-'+colData.RowId).append(td);
            });

        });
        $('#Section-@Model.ReportId-@Model.SectionId').append(table);
    }

    function getSectionDataFail(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
    {
        //alert("Ajax Failed!!!");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Show your `_ReportSection` partial view and js that performs this AJAX call

Comment: Please show code of your partial view and action as well.

Comment: What is the type of `Model` in this context?

Comment: Can you please show your AJAX call from _ReportSection ?

Comment: Ajax call is returning single object data which is correct. Problem is that both time same AJAX call is made with same parameter.(parameters for second object)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I did a work around. I removed javascript code from partial view and placed in the parent page. This worked for me.

But I was trying to keep sections separate through using javascript inside partial view.

By changing the way it is working fine now.
Still I want to know the reason if someone can explain.